# Error in Angularjs while updating from 1.2.27 to 1.4.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a app which was using 1.2.27 version of Angularjs so I decided to update it to 1.4.7 version of Angularjs. but after doing that I am getting error in Angularjs file.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :                               (angular.js:12477)
    at Function (native)
    at Object.sd.compile (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:212:409)
    at fc.parse (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:238:193)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:117:315
    at n.$watch (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:127:125)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:281:486
    at aa (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:73:90)
    at K (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:62:39)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:54:410)
    at K (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:61:488)
```

In console error chrome is not showing any app javascript error. Can any suggest me how to debug this error.

Comment: well you can try non-minified angular to see more details

Comment: Which I am not getting any error in v1.3.20

Comment: @PetrAveryanov sure I will try

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax differences between the legacy and newer versions of angular.

See [this guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) for how to migrate between angular versions.